# MySQL Join or Subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I need a mysql query for all products last purchased date. My mind has gone blank around joins and subqueries.

3 tables - products (need all records), orders (order header info with date) and order_products which has the product detail lines for the order header.

orders_products has key products_id links to products table
orders_products has key order_id that links to orders table

Data similar to

```
products
product_id 
----------
apples 
bananas
pears 

orders
orders_id date_purchased
------------------------------
 1         2018-06-24 12:37:42
 2         2020-10-27 10:30:00
 3         2019-08-25 16:43:36

orders_products
orders_id products_id
---------------------
1           apples
1           pears
2           bananas
2           pears
2           apples
3           bananas
3           apples
```

A pseudo query would look like
for each product
find last order where order.products.products_id = products.products_id by order.date_purchased desc limit 1

The result needed
Product_id | Date_last_purchased

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and [mre] and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next query:

```
SELECT 
    p.products_id,
    coalesce(MAX(date_purchased), 'never purchased') last_purchased
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders_products op on p.products_id = op.products_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
GROUP BY products_id;
```

Test query on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a73ccacbe99002f13c8a0b69fc03ec6e&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: This also is close, but I get all the orders_products lines. I need the products table to drive the query, to find the most recent date purchased from the orders table based on the product id in the orders_products table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is what you need.

```
SELECT p.product_id, o.date_purchased
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN orders_products op ON op.products_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
GROUP BY op.products_id
ORDER BY o.date_purchased DESC
```

Comment: This is close, but I get one of the purchase dates, not the most recent - Does it need limit or max to find the most recent date_purchased.